# python post web form and contents retrieval

Tags: python, forms, post

Need to submit form fields of the following form in an iterative manner, and retrieve all the good information data obtained once the form is posted in a structured manner as a pipe delmited file:

http://cogcc.state.co.us/cogis/ProductionSearch.asp

> Display Production Data : WELL (checkbox)
>   Year range : 2012 to 2014
>   County : Select ALL
>   Limit Records : (Want all records ) else 5000 (upper limit)

Remaining fields are all blank.

I am using python, and I am unable to achieve the desired results by running some of the earlier similar solutions provided in the forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You owe me a beer! :)

```
/tmp ~ python test2.py 
/tmp ~ cat out.csv 
County,Sequence,Sidetrack,Year,Oil Production(barrels),Oil Sales(barrels),Gas Production(MCF),Gas Sales(MCF),Water Production(barrels),Location
001,05242,00,2014,116,66,,,"2,958",SWSE 22 2S 57W
001,05289,00,2014,268,152,,,"4,080",NWNE 22 2S 57W
```

run `pip install beautifulsoup4 requests` and you are good to go:) set up the value `maxrec` to the desired amount of entries.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import sys

postdata = {
    'grouping_type': "wells",
    'FromYear': '2012',
    'ToYear': '2014',
    'maxrec': '5000'
}

r = requests.post('http://cogcc.state.co.us/cogis/ProductionSearch2.asp',
                  data=postdata, timeout=3600.0)

if r.status_code != 200:
    print("Got status code {}, cannot proceed".format(r.status_code))
    sys.exit(1)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
trlist = soup.findAll('table')[1].findAll("tr")
header = trlist[1]
data = trlist[2:]

with open('out.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csvwriter.writerow([row.get_text() for row in header.find_all("th")])

    for entry in data:
        csvwriter.writerow([' '.join(item.get_text().split())
                            for item in entry.findAll("td")])
```

It seems like if you set `maxrec > 5125` approximately, you will get a server error :/

All the best!

Comment: good stuff @brunsgaard !However required some minor tweaks [row.get_text() should have been just row.text]. A beer is definitely on the cards

Comment: actually I made a little more work on the code the other night.. https://gist.github.com/brunsgaard/c3d12be20fa58c4cbe5c
with that i found 85183 oil wells.